# Updating a field in one object with the value from another a field in another object

Tags: trigger, relationships, ideas

I have searched and tried come up with a solution but I just can seem to do it.  I am new to APEX in SF and what I thought was going to be simple I just can't seem to get to work.

I want to update a field in the Ideas object with the value from a field in a custom object (`TIA_Batch__c`).  The field in the Ideas object is a customer field.  I do have a lookup field in the Ideas object with the value but I don't seem to be able to use that vale to update the field I want to.

The 2 fields I am using are `SME__c` and `TIA_Batch_Owner__c`.  Both of these are fields are in the Ideas object but the `TIA_Batch_Owner__c` values is a look up to another object in `TiA_Batch__c`.  The field in the `TiA_Batch__c` object used with the lookup is `Owner`.

This is code

```
trigger SetSMEAsBatchOwner on Idea (after update) 
{
   for (Idea tia:trigger.new)
   {
      if (tia.SME__c!='')
      tia.SME__c=tia.TIA_Batch_Owner__c;
   }
}
```

I have wondered if I need to refer to field in the TIA_Batch__c object but if I do I'm not sure how to.  So if someone could steer me to some documentation that outlines what I should be doing I'll gladly read it.

Comment: you are trying to update a with a value of look-up field..is it correct ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to change your trigger from **after update** to **before update** , **before insert**
and probably add a check for empty owner field as well

```
trigger SetSMEAsBatchOwner on Idea (before insert, before update) 
{
   for (Idea tia:trigger.new)
   {
      if (tia.SME__c !='' && tia.TIA_Batch_Owner__c != '')
         tia.SME__c = tia.TIA_Batch_Owner__c;
   }
}
```